# Django "ProgrammingError at /create-post" usnig heroku postgres as database host

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to create a blog website in django using postgres with heroku in the cloud. When trying to submit the post using forms from django I get this error "ProgrammingError at /create-post
column "title" of relation "main_post" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "main_post" ("author_id", "title", "description"... "

**This is my view for creating posts**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import RegisterForm, PostForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate



@login_required(login_url="/login")
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'main/home.html')

@login_required(login_url="/login")
def create_post(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect("/home")
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'main/create_post.html', {"form": form})
```

**This is my forms.py file**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Post

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ["title", "description"]
```

**This is my Post model**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + "\n" + self.description
```

**This is the error**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1VSB.png)

Comment: have you made the migrations

Comment: **Yes I did it**

Answer (score 0):

Delete your migrations folder and re-migrate like this:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname
python manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001
python manage.py migrate
```

And then try